# Restore over-discharged LiPo batteries ~2.0V/cell

Tags: lipo-batteries

I have a LiPo battery which is ~2.0V/cell, how can I restore it safely? By "safely" I mean how can this be controlled as I know LiPo batteries can be dangerous.

Comment: This question is highly specific about battery chemistry and is outside the scope of SE.Drones.

Comment: @KennSebesta Disagree, this is related to drones in my opinion, but we can see how the community reacts

Comment: @Danil, I see where you're coming from but we have to be careful not to define appropriate/inappropriate just by the volume of responses. If you could reinforce the question with Drone specific parts, then it  becomes relevant to the community.  However, as it is there's nothing in the question or answers which is specific to our needs. A battery-powered phone, toaster, or 3D printer would presumably have the same kind of answers, which is how I know that that it's outside of scope. Is that helpful?

Comment: @KennSebesta - People on here are willing to let legal matters fly ... this is a lot more on-topic than that is.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 that's likely a conversation which should move to meta, but my personal experience has been very different. I spent significant time working with the FAA and developed the first curriculum for and gave the first certifications for drone night flight.  AFAIK we were the first Part 107 pilots to fly in Class B airspace. But in a decade I've never once had to resurrect a battery at 2V/cell. That's a general battery chemistry question. Others experiences are different, but AFAIAA, every country today has regulations which affect drones uniquely..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, I'll add the usual statement that mistreated LiPos can be dangerous and you are almost always better getting new ones.

In some cases, a 'smart' battery charger will refuse to charge cells which have dropped between a certain (manufacturer-determined) voltage. In this case, you can connect the battery to a current limited voltage source and charge the batteries manually with a very low trickle current - 0.1 to 0.2C is more than enough. It will take a while, but speed is not the aim here. You might be able to do this with the charger, by telling it the battery is a different type, or by using a separate supply. In either case, you must ensure the max voltage is within the normal range for the LiPo (4.2V/cell.)

You should only attempt recovery of a suspect battery in a safe, supervised environment - charging is the most likely time for such a battery to fail, and particularly so if it has been over-discharged.

Answer (score 1):

Before I answer, I will say that LiPos are dangerous. If at all possible, it is safer to get new batteries and safely dispose of the damaged one.

Now that I’ve said that, I recently let my goggle battery discharge too low after a long session.

The cells dropped to around 2.5V, and only one would show up in my charger.

After waiting a while, the cells ‘stabilised’ for lack of a better word, and they all showed up on my charger, though they were all at around 2.5V, which is obviously far too low.

I hooked up my LiPo to my charger in a fire-resistant place, and set it for a balance charge at around 0.2C. Lower should be better.

Eventually, the cells recovered, though I am still wary about using the battery.